# Is $\Bbb{R}$ finitely generated over the algebraics?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, real-numbers

Let $K$ be the field of all algebraic numbers.  Then does there exist an algebraically independent set of numbers $\pi_1, \dots, \pi_n$ such that $\Bbb{R} = K(\pi_1, \dots, \pi_n)$?

I don't know where to begin on this one or if it's even possible with my limited tools to solve it.  Any ideas?

One thing I know is that if $r \notin L = K(\pi_1, \dots, \pi_n)$, then the minimal polynomial of $r$ over $K$ must have at least one transcendental coefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that if $K$ is a countable field, then any finitely generated extension $K(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is also countable.

One way to do this is to first show that the ring $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is countable, and then use the fact that $K(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the fraction field of $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: $\mathbf R$ is uncountable.

Comment: I know this but not sure how to apply it.  Since elements of $L = K(\pi_1, \dots, \pi_n)$ can be written as a countable sum of terms of the form $a_i \pi_1^{e_1} \pi_2^{e_2} \cdots \pi_n^{e_n}$ with $a_i \in K$.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: Are elements of $L$ not rational functions in the $\pi_i$'s, with coefficients in $K$?

Comment: @EnjoysMath, That is not true: the rational fraction $1/(x+1)\in K(x)$ cannot be written —if $x$ is not lgebraic over $K$— as a sum of element of the form $\alpha x^e$ with $\alpha\in K$ and $e\in\mathbb Z$.